# Minimum distance between two disjoint compact subsets.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Given $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint compact subsets of a metric space $M$ prove that there exists $x_0 \in X$ and $y_0 \in Y$ such that for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ we have $d(x_0,y_0)\leq d(x,y)$.

How would one go about this? and are the $x_0,y_0$ values unique?

Comment: Can't you really think of any examples to try and see whether this stands a chance to be unique? What kind of properties do you know about compact sets?

Comment: I am pretty sure they are not unique... Consider $X=\{(0,y)|y\in [0,1]\}$ and $Y=\{(1,y)|y\in [0,1]\}$. They are distinct compact subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ but the $x_0$ and $y_0$ values would not be unique.

Comment: Good! What about properties of compact sets?

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the infimum of the set $\{d(x,y)\,|\,x \in X,\, y\in Y\}\subset \Bbb R$.